# How to check the type of a value being one defined in a union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I use `@azure/msal-react` and `@azure/msal-browser` to implement authentication in React with Typescript.

My problem is that `event.payload` is known by TypeScript to have type `EventPayload` (union), however it doesn't let me check the exact type (e.g. `AuthenticationResult`) using the `instanceof` operator.

How can I check the exact type of `event.payload`?

```
import {
  EventType,
  AuthenticationResult,
  PublicClientApplication,
} from "@azure/msal-browser";
```

```
export declare type EventPayload = AccountInfo | PopupRequest | RedirectRequest | SilentRequest | SsoSilentRequest | EndSessionRequest | AuthenticationResult | PopupEvent | null;
```

```
msalInstance.addEventCallback((event) => {
  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
    if (event.payload instanceof AuthenticationResult) {
      // 'AuthenticationResult' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
      ...   
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should explicitly check event.payload, and you cannot use instanceof, because ts doesn't know your type in runtime. Because you are using a callback in your event handler

Suggest adding helper function, [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBW1CA3CAO2ABVwIAuKBYAJwEtCBzDAXw1EigEEBXYABZFg9AMZwRAe0IAlCAl4AbYFFTwkUAGTosOQnAC2lKAHI4-ASbYdyUAAqSwvMAFECxVbETRtmHLndgKhMwR2crdgAzXkJRKUIoegQ+QSgACnwgqDdhOzgQRUk4ABMASipMxIQeC2ExCXppOQVlHX9aCGBeWgTMgH4AOnxhMi5kcdMUy2sIAA9Q2hViiFFFOA6oTmgc4jyCouLPKbrxeOalFQAfezDXQKhrwiVFAG4MUWkaKEiE1AzAqg7YB7QolUqqAB8bUSkXSw2Ig3hpFsAEJUE9FIpwX4cPRYWkklN-sJStjdP5sAB6SlQD60DpxTbkclQdjYdjsIA)

```
type Base = { // for simplicity add some base type
    eventType: string
}
type AuthenticationResult = Base & {
    name: 'auth'
}
type PopupEvent = Base & {
    event: string
}

// helper function that checks type
function isAuth (evt: EventPayload): evt is AuthenticationResult {
    return evt?.name === 'auth'
}
export declare type EventPayload = AuthenticationResult | PopupEvent | null;
const fn = (event: EventPayload) => {
  if (event?.eventType != null) {
    if (isAuth(event)) {
      // correct type
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. **because ts doesn't know your type in runtime, why its runtime?**, what do you mean by **why its runtime?**?

Comment: The problem is that `AuthenticationResult` doesn't have such `name` property. So, how can I decide the type in that case?

Comment: Check how auth is different from other types

Comment: Thanks. So, the only way to go is to check for properties that are specific for `AuthenticationResult`? Is that the canonical way of doing this? What if more types have the same properties?

Comment: Types and interfaces are not available in js, your code compiles to js, and your event handler is called in runtime, meaning you can detect the value when code runs, yes that’s only way to check the type in typescript